# Select data from daily lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table in my database that looks something like this:
ID | datetime | value1 | value2 | value3

Now I want to select the datetime, value1, value2 and value3 where value1 is the lowest (MIN(value1)) per day. An example below (with arrows indicating the rows that need to be selected):

```
ID | datetime            | value1 | value2 | value3
1  | 2014-01-01 00:06:00 | 10     | 15     | 20
2  | 2014-01-01 00:12:00 | 5      | 15     | 22     <--
3  | 2014-01-01 00:18:00 | 12     | 45     | 25
4  | 2014-01-02 00:06:00 | 1      | 25     | 10     <--
5  | 2014-01-02 00:12:00 | 12     | 45     | 25
6  | 2014-01-02 00:18:00 | 13     | 25     | 10
7  | 2014-01-03 00:06:00 | 17     | 35     | 95
8  | 2014-01-03 00:12:00 | 15     | 75     | 10
9  | 2014-01-03 00:18:00 | 12     | 75     | 35     <--
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    datetime,
    MIN(value1) as value1,
    value2,
    value3
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    DAY(datetime)
ORDER BY
    datetime ASC                                
LIMIT 50
```

This gives me a result, however not what I was expecting. The datetime and value2, value3 do not come from the row where the daily minimum is found.

Can someone explain me what I've done wrong?

Furthermore: would I be able to combine this (with a selfjoin or something) where I would get the minimum value of the day as above, and from the resulting result set I would then only select the rows where for example value2 > 20 && value2 < 60 && value3 > 10?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
*
from
Table1 t
inner join (select date(datetime) as dt, min(value1) v from Table1 group by dt) st
on date(t.datetime) = st.dt and t.value1 = st.v
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15f68/1/0)</kbd>
- see plenty more examples how to do it in this manual entry: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    SELECT
    datetime,
    MIN(value1) as value1,
    value2,
    value3
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    DAY(datetime)
ORDER BY
    value1 ASC                                
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: try by changing the DAY(datetime) to datetime alone. it will work. this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select t1.datentime, t1.value1, value2, value3
from test t1, ( select date(datentime) datentime,min(value1) value1
        from test
        group by date(datentime)) dummy
where date(t1.datentime)=dummy.datentime and t1.value1=dummy.value1
```

here is working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/000eb4/10)